# Post params into http link

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to implement example with webflux which sends params into http link:

```
String convertedString = "key=value&key=value";

    Mono<String> transactionMono = Mono.just(convertedString);
            return client.post().uri("http://www.some_host.com/receive.php")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0")
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                    // .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                    .body(transactionMono, String.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(NotificationEchoResponse.class);
```

The request should look like: `http://www.some_host.com/receive.php?key=value&key=value`

What is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. However, parameters are not part of the body, but part of the URI.

This is how your code should look like:

```
String convertedString = "key=value&key=value";

return client.post().uri("http://www.some_host.com/receive.php?" + convertedString)
        .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        // .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(NotificationEchoResponse.class);
```